# VB script for auto switch windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to auto switch between 2 windows which are dashboards from the same program, but run in seperate windows. I saw the following:

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
    WScript.Sleep 30000
    WshShell.SendKeys("%{TAB}")
Loop
```

There is a note: If you want to stop it, then you need to kill the process called "wscript".
Can someone tell me how to include this kill command, as when i run the code i get stuck in an endless loop and need to restart pc to stop it.

Perhaps there is a better solution even? its for an office tv that needs to rotate between dashboards of data on seperate windows.

Thanks!

Comment: They just mean kill the process from the Task Manager. Control Alt Del. Did you try that?